# How do I control the sort function in Photos?

Tags: photos, sort

Is there some way to disable the sorting of photos within an album so that I can retain the order of the photos in the manner that I would like?

Comment: Which albums do you have in mind?  As far as I can see (on a quick test), a normal album lets you manually sort the images (and disables any previously set sort order), while smart and shared albums ask for one of the sorting options.

Comment: Please update the OP with the platform and OS version you have in mind. I have supplied an answer below for both macOS 13 and iOS 16, but it would help to know what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

**For Photos on macOS:**

If you right click on an Album in the sidebar and choose `Sort` you will see the current sort order ticked.

Now, you can drag and drop individual images to rearrange manually, dropping them in-between other images (you'll see the other images move aside to indicate space is being made).

Once you've finished your rearrangement, if you check the `Sort` option again, you'll see all the sort methods unticked, indicating a manual sort. You can't untick a sort method, the images are always sorted ...until they aren't.

This method only applies to normal Albums, it won't work for Smart Albums, which always have one of the 3 methods (name, oldest, newest).

**For Photos on iOS:**

Enter your Album, press the ellipsis button top right, select Sort | Custom Order. You can now drag images about into your preferred order.

Smart Albums aren't supported in iOS.